Formula to change how a number is displayed in crystal reports
I’m creating a pallet label for a customer in crystal reports, and need to change the weight field data so I can add it into a barcode
Example, 663.12 to display as 066312
The end figure will need be 6 digits in lenght, but the start figure could be 7 digits in lenght with deicmal point
Is there a formula to achieve this
the final figure is then added into the barcode
Thanks
Lee
I can sort of achive this by using the left right functions, but its only a work around
"0" & left(({@net weight}),3) & right(({@net weight}),2)
this is ok until the weight goes above 1000 then i get a return of 010000

Try this formula.
CStr(663.12 * 100, "000000")

This converts the data to a string.  The format string ensures there are always 6 characters in the string output, and will default to a leading zero when the value being converted has less than 6 characters.  Multiplying the value by 100 removes the decimal.
Using this formula, your value of 663.12 would become 066312.  While a value of 63.12 would become 006312. and a value of 0.01 would become 000001.

Great, this worked fine. thank you. final formula was cstr ({stockem.weightkg}*{oppickm.quantity} * 100, "000000")
